# How to read lines from 2 different dataframes at one time in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have 2 data frames: `normal`,`cancer`
and now I have a for loop to read them:

```
for line in normal,cancer():    
    if len(line) < 20:        
        print('Insufficient')      
        continue
```

which means I want to read these 2 data by line at one time in a for loop.

**How can I accomplish this?**

Comment: Are you talking about Pandas data frames? If so, in most cases you probably don't need to use loops as all.

Comment: Have you looked at [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)?

Comment: yes!!! that's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, should `cancer()` be `cancer`? Is it a function?

You could try doing a `for lineNum, line in enumerate(normal)` and then accessing `cancer` like `cancer[lineNum]`